# How to have both emphasis/italics and Chinese font in pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, cjk

This is a pdflatex version of the question How to have both emphasis/italics and Chinese font. Consider

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
A \emph{B} C \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}年\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compilation result]

Notice that the letter B is not emphasized. How can I fix this behavior?

Just to be more precise, here is my pdflatex log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.5.24)  1 SEP 2022 16:21
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**crap
(./crap.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
\linespacing=\dimen138
\normalparindent=\dimen139
\normaltopskip=\skip47
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2021/10/15 v2.17l AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip48

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen140
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen141
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2021/08/26 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count185
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count186
\leftroot@=\count187
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count188
\DOTSCASE@=\count189
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box50
\strutbox@=\box51
\big@size=\dimen142
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count190
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count191
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count192
\dspbrk@lvl=\count193
\tag@help=\toks17
\row@=\count194
\column@=\count195
\maxfields@=\count196
\andhelp@=\toks18
\eqnshift@=\dimen143
\alignsep@=\dimen144
\tagshift@=\dimen145
\tagwidth@=\dimen146
\totwidth@=\dimen147
\lineht@=\dimen148
\@envbody=\toks19
\multlinegap=\skip49
\multlinetaggap=\skip50
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks20
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2938.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2939.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 397
.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
\copyins=\insert199
\abstractbox=\box52
\listisep=\skip51
\c@part=\count197
\c@section=\count198
\c@subsection=\count266
\c@subsubsection=\count267
\c@paragraph=\count268
\c@subparagraph=\count269
\c@figure=\count270
\c@table=\count271
\abovecaptionskip=\skip52
\belowcaptionskip=\skip53
\captionindent=\dimen149
\thm@style=\toks21
\thm@bodyfont=\toks22
\thm@headfont=\toks23
\thm@notefont=\toks24
\thm@headpunct=\toks25
\thm@preskip=\skip54
\thm@postskip=\skip55
\thm@headsep=\skip56
\dth@everypar=\toks26
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/CJK.sty
Package: CJK 2015/04/18 4.8.4

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/mule/MULEenc.sty
Package: MULEenc 2015/04/18 4.8.4
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/CJK.enc
File: CJK.enc 2015/04/18 4.8.4
Now handling font encoding C00 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C00
Now handling font encoding C05 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C05
Now handling font encoding C09 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C09
Now handling font encoding C10 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C10
Now handling font encoding C20 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C20
Now handling font encoding C19 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C19
Now handling font encoding C40 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C40
Now handling font encoding C42 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C42
Now handling font encoding C43 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C43
Now handling font encoding C50 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C50
Now handling font encoding C52 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C52
Now handling font encoding C49 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C49
Now handling font encoding C60 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C60
Now handling font encoding C61 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C61
Now handling font encoding C63 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C63
Now handling font encoding C64 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C64
Now handling font encoding C65 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C65
Now handling font encoding C70 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C70
Now handling font encoding C31 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C31
Now handling font encoding C32 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C32
Now handling font encoding C33 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C33
Now handling font encoding C34 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C34
Now handling font encoding C35 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C35
Now handling font encoding C36 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C36
Now handling font encoding C37 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C37
Now handling font encoding C80 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C80
Now handling font encoding C81 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C81
Now handling font encoding C01 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C01
Now handling font encoding C11 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C11
Now handling font encoding C21 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C21
Now handling font encoding C41 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C41
Now handling font encoding C62 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C62
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \selectfont on input line 755.
\CJK@indent=\box53
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks27
\inpenc@posthook=\toks28
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-01-12 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count272
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box54
)
(./crap.aux)
\openout1 = `crap.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C00/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C05/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C09/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C10/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C20/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C19/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C40/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C42/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C43/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C50/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C52/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C49/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C60/mj/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C61/mj/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C63/mj/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C64/mj/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C65/mj/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C70/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C31/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C32/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C33/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C34/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C35/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C36/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C37/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C80/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C81/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C01/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C11/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C21/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C41/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for C62/song/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 4.
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 4.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/UTF8/UTF8.bdg
File: UTF8.bdg 2015/04/18 4.8.4
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/UTF8/UTF8.enc
File: UTF8.enc 2015/04/18 4.8.4
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/UTF8/UTF8.chr
File: UTF8.chr 2015/04/18 4.8.4
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for C70+gbsn on input line 
6.

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/UTF8/c70gbsn.fd
File: c70gbsn.fd 2008/10/03 4.8.1
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/UTF8/c70gbsn.fdx
File: c70gbsn.fdx 2012/05/07 4.8.3
) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./crap.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2822 strings out of 478287
 36685 string characters out of 5849289
 327811 words of memory out of 5000000
 20836 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 473600 words of font info for 45 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1302 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 69i,5n,76p,253b,240s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/sh
are/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb></usr/share/tex
live/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts
/type1/arphic/gbsnu/gbsnu5e.pfb>
Output written on crap.pdf (1 page, 32337 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 23 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 13 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: It works for me, both with TeXlive 2017 and 2022.

Comment: It's odd, you have TeX Live 2022 but `LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1`. I don't know if this is the issue though.

Comment: When the font provides bold, what it seems to do from the comments, then the pdf viewer used may be the problem. Try e.g. a browser like FireFox and/or Adobe Reader. For TeX Live 2022 may be a driver is missing?

Comment: show the log-file and not only the terminal output.

Comment: @MS-SPO: I tried looking at the output pdf file in TeXWorks, GIMP, PDF Arranger and Gnome Document Viewer. It looks the same in all of them: no italicizing of the letter B.